# Animation finishes on first frame

Tags: iphone, animation, cocos2d-iphone

I play an animation like this:

```
- (CCSprite *)explodeWithBatchNode:(CCSpriteBatchNode *)batchNode andAnimation:(CCAnimation *)ani
{       
    CCSprite *explosionSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:batchNode.texture rect  :CGRectMake(0, 0, 154,119)];

    CCAction *goldenExplosionAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:ani];
    [explosionSprite runAction:goldenExplosionAction];

    return explosionSprite;     
}
```

Everything works fine, the only problem is that the animation stops at the first frame instead of the last. How can I have it finish on the last one?, also, how can I know that the animation has finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+ (id) actionWithAnimation:CCAnimation *) a restoreOriginalFrame:(BOOL)    b`

it's a method of a CCAnimate action. Just put the second argument to NO

In your case
`CCAction *goldenExplosionAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:ani restoreOriginalFrame:NO];`

To understand the animation was finished create a callback, that will be called after animation like this:

```
id animation = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation: someAnimation];
id callback = [CCCallfunc actionWithTarget: targetObject selector: @selector(mySelector)];
id sequence = [CCSequence actions: animation, callback, nil];
[mySprite runAction: sequence];
```

So after animation is finished targetObject's mySelector method will be called.
If you want to pass some data through a callback and/or a sender use CCCallFuncN or CCCallFuncND actions

Comment: restoreOriginalFrame is deprecated. Now, you'd do: ani.restoreOriginalFrame = YES; before running it.